# Cannot find module './middlewares'

Tags: javascript, express

I'm new in express.js and success running server on port 3000 in one file index.js but when i trying to using cors and body parser in different file I have error `Error: Cannot find module './middlewares'`.

this is the structure project folder

- project_folder

  - index.js
  - middlewares

    - cors.js
    - bodyParser.js
  - configs

    - server.js
    - database.js

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const middlewares = require('./middlewares');

app.use(middlewares.cors());
app.use(middlewares.bodyParser());

configs.database.setupDatabase();
configs.server.startServer(app);
```

cors.js

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');

        next();
    });
};
```

bodyParser.js

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
};
```

server.js

```
const PORT = 3000;

module.exports = {
    startServer: (app) => {
        try {
            app.listen(PORT, () => {
                console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error starting server:', error);
        }
    }
};
```

database.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const MONGODB_URI = `mongodb://localhost:27017/lat6`;

module.exports = {
    setupDatabase: async () => {
        try {
            await mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, {
                useNewUrlParser: true,
                useUnifiedTopology: true
            });
            console.log('Connected to database');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error connecting to database:', error);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

looking at your folder/file layout to import the code you have in the middleware folder will have to be completed by giving the path `.js` file, that has the exported function. In your case `cors.js` and `bodyParser.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const middlewareCors= require('./middlewares/cors');
const middlewaresParser = require('./middlewares/bodyParser');


app.use(middlewareCors.cors());
app.use(middlewaresParser.bodyParser());

configs.database.setupDatabase();
configs.server.startServer(app);
```

Comment: oh thanks, i understand now. './middlewares' it refer to middlewares.js.

Comment: i think it would be cool if can call cors and body parser with only require('./middlewares') and call it with app.use(middlewares.cors());
app.use(middlewares.bodyParser());

Comment: You can,  put all of your middleware functions in a file called middlewares.js and export them.